# Unable to create index on solr, when using Zookeeper

Tags: replication, solr, zookeeper

Evening,

I've created a what I believe to be a simple SOLR cluster, with Zookeeper (external binaries instead of the embeded). For simplicity, this cluster is:

Master: SOLR1
Slave: SOLR2

Both device have Zookeeper running on them until I start to bridge out into other devices.

SOLR is set to start with -Denable.master=true and -Denable.slave=true and include the -z host flag as per the instructions. I can see my index being generated, and now on my slave node within the SOLR admin console, I get the following error:

> SolrCore Initialization Failures
>   fts_en: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.request.XSLTResponseWriter'
>   Please check your logs for more information

My index is called fts_en. On the slave node, if I review the log files, I get the following information:

> 2016-01-05 17:06:55.836 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-2-thread-1-processing-n:10.177.208.19:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be created
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [fts_en]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.run(CoreContainer.java:491)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:232)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [fts_en]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:756)
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:462)
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:453)
>           ... 5 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.request.XSLTResponseWriter'
>           at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:824)
>           at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:665)
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:742)
>           ... 7 more

I cannot work out why, can anyone assist please?

Centos 6.5
SOLR 5.4.0
Zookeeper: 3.4.7